# C# Lambda in set property

Tags: c#, properties, lambda, set

reading through c# examples i found usage of lambda in set property:

```
 private bool _inProgress;
 public bool InProgress
        {
            get {
                return _inProgress;
            }
            set { Set(() => InProgress, ref _inProgress, value); }
        }
```

However it's not working for me, i get

```
the name "Set" does not exist in current context
```

error.

i found that this syntax `{Set(() => InProgress, value);}` equals `{return InProgress = value;}`is that correct? However i'm still getting  `the name "Set" does not exist in current context` error.

Comment: look at the class where you found it, you'll finds that it inherits another class, so the Set is probably a member of a super class, to make it work your class will have to inherit that class too

Comment: Thanks, i didn't noticed it it inherits from mvvn light ViewModelBase it solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the class where you found it, you'll finds that it inherits from another class, so the `Set` is probably a member of a super class, to make it work your class will have to inherit that class too.